# How to remove blank rows from csv file using batch?

Tags: excel, csv, batch-file, vbscript, export-to-csv

It's my first time programming with batch files and I was asked to do a program capable of converting .xlsm files into .csv, without having to open Excel to do so. To do so, I use this .bat file:

```
extoc.vbs integration.xlsm integration.csv 
Taskkill /IM EXCEL.EXE /F

@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION


call :StripBlankLines "integration.csv"

goto :eof
:StripBlankLines
For %%x in ("%~1") do set OutF=integration_er.csv
if exist "%OutF%" del "%OutF%"
set FirstLine=1
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%B in (%*) do (
    call :TrimWS %%B
    if not "!Line!"=="" (
        if "!FirstLine!"=="1" (
            set FirstLine=0
        ) else (
            >>"%OutF%" echo.
        )
        call :write !Line!
    )
)
goto :eof

:TrimWS
set Line=%*
goto :eof 

:write
>>"%OutF%"<NUL set /p Dummy=%*
goto :eof
```

Together with the .vbs file:

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
WScript.Echo "Please specify the source and the destination files. Usage: ExcelToCsv <xls/xlsx source file> <csv destination file>"
Wscript.Quit
End If

csv_format = 6

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
dest_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))

Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)

oBook.SaveAs dest_file, csv_format

oExcel.Quit

oBook.Close False
```

The problem in here is that I get, as a final result, a giant CSV containing all the information from the original .xlsm file, but also several lines filled with nothing but commas, as you can see bellow:

```
data, data, data,, data, data, data, data, data, data
data, data, data,, data, data, data, data, data, data
data, data, data,, data, data, data, data, data, data
data, data, data,, data, data, data, data, data, data
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
```

While I need to have something like this:

```
data, data, data,, data, data, data, data, data, data
data, data, data,, data, data, data, data, data, data
data, data, data,, data, data, data, data, data, data
data, data, data,, data, data, data, data, data, data
```

I know these commas come from blank rows in excel, but I can't use a VBA Macro to remove all the blank rows in excel because it is a HUGE sheet and my PC crashes everytime I try to do it. So, if there's some way to solve this through VBS or BATCH I would be REALLY glad!

Comment: `Replace(<your csv>,",,,,,,,,," & vbCrLf,"")`?

Comment: Didn't work. But stil, thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:TrimWS
set Line=%*
set "line=%line:,=%"
if defined line set "line=%*"
goto :eof
```

Replace each `,` in `line` with *nothing*. If the result is *nothing* then `line` will be undefined, ie. empty. If it isn't re-load it with the original value.

BTW - If you set `FirstLine` to *nothing* (`set firstline="`) or *something* (anything, just not *nothing*) then you can use `if defined firstline` to detect its *current* state so you don't need `delayedexpansion`.

---

(rewritten)

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL


call :StripBlankLines "integration.csv"

goto :eof
:StripBlankLines
For %%x in ("%~1") do set OutF=integration_er.csv
if exist "%OutF%" del "%OutF%"
set FirstLine=1
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%B in (%*) do (
    call :TrimWS %%B
    if defined line (
        if defined firstline (
            set "FirstLine="
        ) else (
            >>"%OutF%" echo.
        )
        call :write %%B
    )
)
goto :eof

:TrimWS
set Line=%*
set "line=%line:,=%"
goto :eof 

:write
>>"%OutF%"<NUL set /p Dummy=%*
goto :eof
```

Since `line` will contain the same as `%%B`, you can use `%%B` *provided* it doesn't consist of just-commas. Hence you can despatch `%%B` to your `:trimws` routine, and `line` will be set to either *nothing* (in the case of all-commas) or *something* (anything) otherwise.

You can then simply interpret `line` being either defined or not to output `%%B` through your `:write` routine, as `:write` will only be invoked when `%%B` does not contain all-commas but also isn't empty (the `for/f` will take care of that).

Setting `firstline` to *something* at the start means `if defined firstline` will be true initially, so you set it to *nothing* and thereafter `if defined firstline` will be false.

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned.

The `setlocal` should remain in order that the `cmd` environment does not accumulate values as batch routines run. It ensures that any changes made to the environment variables are discarded when the routine terminates

Comment: Thanks man! It worked perfectly in my code! Also, thanks for the tip ;)

Comment: Also, how could I adapt the code to remove the delayedexpansion? I got this part of the code online

Comment: @PedroMartins You're going to have to explain what `delayedexpansion` is...

Comment: @PedroMartins oh woops! I didn't realised delayed expansion was a standard batch thing... My bad!

Comment: No problems, @Sancarn!

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, why not just use a single line:

```bat
FindStr "[^,]" "integration.csv">"integration_er.csv"
```